# Get Camera 2d position by 3 image points (1D)

Tags: math, 2d, coordinate

i have an image and 3 points with following datas for each point:

- x and y 2d-world coordinates
- x image coordinate

how can i calculate the camera orientation (only left/right) and the 2d-world position?

thanks.

edit: the image is a normal photography (so perspective projection). The world coordinate is a top view of a map, so Orthographic projection).

Comment: What projection do you use?

Comment: thanks. i added these infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a point in world space, the projection can be expressed as

```
             (x - cx) * cos(phi) - (y - cy) * sin(phi)
proj(x, y) = -----------------------------------------
             (x - cx) * sin(phi) + (y - cy) * cos(phi)
```

`cx` and `cy` are the camera position and `phi` is the camera rotation. The projection will result in a value in camera coordinates (not image coordinates). To transform image coordinates to camera coordinates, usw

```
cameraX(imageX) = (2 * imageX / W - 1) * tan(fovy / 2) * ratio
```

`W` is the pixel width of the image, `fovy` is the vertical field of view, `ratio` is the image's aspect ratio.

Then you want to solve the system of equations formed by the three given points. There is an analytic solution, but it is quite complex. So you're left with numerical (probably least-squares) solvers. Pick one, plug in the formula and get your result. Since you optimize for both a position and an angle, you may want to normalize the values so that they have a similar range. I got quite good results with [levmar](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/) for similar problems if you're unsure what optimizer to use.

This all assumes that the camera does not distort the image.

Comment: thanks, but i have problems to understand this. why fovy and not fovx? And do i have to use your image-to-camera-coordinates formula for proj(x) and proj(y) without adjustments?  it would be really helpful to if you could write down the full equation for one point..

Comment: Field of view is usually specified for the vertical direction. You can also use `tan(fovx/2)` instead of `tan(fovy/2)*ratio`. You must transform your image x-coordinates into camera coordinates before putting them in the equation. `proj(x,y)` will also produce camera coordinates.

Comment: i'm a bit confused: where is the image x-coordinate in the equation? I thought the x and y are the world positions. cx, cy and phi are the unknowns. so is proj(x) the image x-coordinate transformed in camera coordinates? But which value do i have to use then for proj(y)?

Comment: The equations are of the form `proj(mapX, mapY) = cameraX(imageX)`.

Comment: thanks again. but what do you mean here with the field of view? i couldn't find a general definition of a fov for images (only video games or i have to measure it, both not suitable). i have the focal length and the ange of view..

Comment: Field of view is the angle of view.